# After creating a folder with php inside a sub-folder it redirects to the root folder

Tags: php, refresh

I am creating a file system that lists all the folders in your server. I can create and delete   any folder. But the problem is when I am inside a sub-folder and delete another sub-folder, the website redirects me back to the root folder. I want to refresh and update only the changes rather than redirect me to the root folder.

here is the code of how I am creating new folder:

```
<form id="folder-form" name="folder-form" method="post" action="my-home.php">
     <p>Create a new folder</p>
     <div class="folderInput">
        <input type="text" name="folder-name" id="name" placeholder="Folder Name"/>
     </div>
     <div class="folderBtn">
         <button type="submit" value="Create Folder" id="createFolder">Ok</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

and this is how I am retrieving the new folder information using isset:

```
if (isset($_POST['folder-name'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['currentDir'].$_SESSION['folderName'].'/';
    $folder = $_SESSION['currentDir'].$_SESSION['folderName']."/".$_POST['folder-name'];
    if (!file_exists($folder)) {
        mkdir($folder, 0777);
    }
}
```

This is the delete link:

```
<a href="#" id="delete" onclick="deleteForm.submit()">Delete</a>
```

and this is how I am retrieving the information using the isset

```
if (isset($_POST['select'])){
    foreach ($_POST['select'] as $file) {
        deleteFiles($_SESSION['currentDir'].$_SESSION['folderName']."/".$file);
    }
}
```

Note that in every row I have a checkbox for the delete function:

```
<input name="select[]" type="checkbox" class="select" value="folder name"/><
```

Comment: Please show your delete code...

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to have files or directories with 777 permissions.

Comment: I edited the post with my delete code